# Find values of $x^4 - (x-1)^4$ where $x^5-(x-1)^5=\frac{1}{5}$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, contest-math

I've been trying to solve this problem:

> Across all solutions of $x^5 - (x-1)^5 = \frac{1}{5}$, find the possible values of $x^4 - (x - 1)^4$.

I've tried the following ideas:

- Expanding the equations using the Binomial Theorem, we find that $x^5 - (x-1)^5 = 5 x^4 - 10 x^3 + 10 x^2 - 5 x + 1$ and $x^4 - (x - 1)^4 = 4 x^3 - 6 x^2 + 4 x - 1$. These don't seem to help us express one in terms of the other, though: multiplying the latter by $x$ yields $4x^4 - 6x^3 + 4x^2 - x$, and the coefficients don't match that of the expanded $x^5 - (x - 1)^5$.
- I also observed that $x^4 - (x - 1)^4 = (x^2 + (x - 1)^2)(x^2 - (x - 1)^2) = (2x^2 - 2x + 1)(2x - 1)$ by factoring a difference of squares. But this only helps if we can find $x^2$ and $(x - 1)^2$, which leaves me back where I started.
- I also tried dividing the polynomials ($\frac{x^5 - (x-1)^5}{x^4 - (x-1)^4}$), and got a quotient of $-\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{9 x}{8} - \frac{9}{16}$ and a remainder of $\frac{15 x^2}{8} - \frac{13x}{8} + \frac{7}{16}$. As far as I can see, there's nothing interesting here either.
- Lastly, I've been trying to use properties of complex  numbers (De Moivre's theorem) to try and find something out about the roots. I'll update if I find anything.

I've spent a long time on this problem, and I feel stuck. I've tried searching it up, but I couldn't find it on Google. Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: A quick observation: Graphing $y = x^5$ and $y = (x - 1)^5$ shows that there are two real solutions to $x^5 - (x - 1)^5 = \frac{1}{5}$. It follows that there are two complex solutions as well, because $x^5 - (x - 1)^5$ has degree $4$. Not sure if this is needed for a solution, though.

Comment: Hint: if you write $x=t+\frac{1}{2}$, then the equation $x^5 - (x-1)^5 = \frac{1}{5}$ becomes a biquadratic in $t$, which is easier to solve.

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to range across all complex values, or only real ones?

Comment: By brute force using [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), the value [must be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28+5+x%5E5+-+5+%28x-1%29%5E5+-+1%2C+x%5E4+-+%28x-1%29%5E4+-+z%2C+x+%29+%2F+125) a root of the biquadratic $\,125 z^4 + 90 z^2 - \frac{891}{125}\,$. However, the calculations are laborious to do by hand, so I guess there must be a smarter shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

[WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor+x%5E5-%28x-1%29%5E5-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B5%7D) tells us that
$$
 x^5-(x-1)^5-\frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{5} (5 x^2 - 5 x + 1) (5 x^2 - 5 x + 4)
$$
Just find the zeros of the two quadratic factors and plug the values in $x^4 - (x-1)^4$. Only the first quadratic factor has real zeros, if that matters.

It does not seem to me that this is the intended solution.

Comment: The first equation gives two possible values for $\,x^2 - x\,$, which I believe simplifies the second evaluation to the point of being reasonably workable. Depending on the context, this could well be the intended solution.

Answer (score 0):

By binomial expansion, $x^5-(x-1)^5=5(x^4-2x^3+2x^2-x)+1.$ After dividing by $5$ and factorizing the parenthetic term of this expression, the given equation becomes $(y-0.5)(y+0.5)+0.2=0.04$, where
$$y:=x^2-x+0.5.$$
Then $y^2=0.09$, and hence $y=\pm0.3.$ Write $$z:=x^4-(x-1)^4,$$ which factorizes as $z=2y(2x-1).$

**Case 1:** $y=0.3.\;$ We have $x^2-x+0.2=0$ and so $(2x-1)^2=0.2.$ Then $z=\pm0.6\surd0.2$.

**Case 2:** $y=-0.3.\;$In this case, $x^2-x+0.8=0$ and $(2x-1)^2=-2.2.$ Then $z=\pm0.6\mathrm i\surd2.2$.

The four possible values of $z$ are thus $\pm0.6\surd0.2$ and $\pm0.6\mathrm i\surd2.2$.